# GROUP BY with MAX() in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a table `test` as below:

[image]

I would like to filter rows which have maximum in `number2`, and then maximum in `number1` in the same name.

So, the expected result in table above will be row id 2, and 4:

```
2    cuong    7    10
4    nam      3    8
```

row 2 is opted because it has `number2` is 10 (maximum) and `number1` is 7 (maximum in 5 and 7). And the row 4 is similar.

The result can be obtained by:

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(number1), number2
FROM test
WHERE number2 IN (select max(number2) from test group by `name`)
group by `name`;
```

But this solution is for my assumption table above, in my real problem, it's complicated and has to join lot of tables together, sub query in WHERE clause makes the performance is really really slow.

So, I would like to find a simpler solution which does not use sub query in WHERE clause, just 
only GROUP BY, I also have tried:

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(number1), number2
FROM cuong_test.test
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING number2 = MAX(number2);
```

But it does not work out.

Comment: You are only comparing to `max(number2)` is this the real thing you need to select the row which has the maximum value of `number2` only? your desired result set also satisfies this condition

Comment: What if `max(number1)` is in row with one `id` and `max(number2)` is in row for another `id`? Empty result set? (I assume it's inside one group of `name`)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: I also continue to filter `max(number1)` in the list of rows which have `max(number2)`, that's why row id 2 is chosen.

Comment: @AlmaDo: I am not sure I can get your point? Please could you explain more.

Comment: @CuongLe for example, we have rows `(100, 'coung', 5, 8)` and `(101, 'coung', 7, 4)`. Thus, `max(number1)` is `7`, `max(number2)` is `8`, but first is in row with `id=101` while second is in row with `id=100`

Comment: @AlmaDo: It's not expectation, for your example. it should be the first `(100, 'cuong', 5, 8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to most easily be done using `not exists` to get the maximum numbers:

```
SELECT id, name, number1, number2
FROM test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from test t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        (t2.number2 > t.number2 or
                         t2.number2 = t.number2 and
                         t2.number1 > t.number1
                        )
                 );
```

In MySQL, you can also do this with `group_concat()` magic:

```
select id, name,
       substring_index(group_concat(number1 order by number2 desc), ',', 1) as number1,
       max(number2) as number2
from test t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is trickier than it looks. I believe you're going to need to `JOIN` the results of two subqueries.

First, you need a query to determine the id numbers of the rows meeting your first criterion.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
  FROM test AS a
  JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(number1) AS m,
                name
           FROM test
          GROUP BY name
       ) AS b ON a.name = b.name
```

This looks up the id numbers of all the rows which contain the `MAX(number1)` for each name.   Your other subquery does this for `MAX(number2)`.

Then you `JOIN` them by id to find the rows that match ... that is, that contain the max values for both numbers.

```
SELECT x.id, x.name, x.m AS max_number1, y.m AS max_number2
  FROM (
        SELECT a.id, a.name
          FROM test
          JOIN (
                 SELECT MAX(number1) AS m,
                        name
                   FROM test
                  GROUP BY name
               ) AS b ON a.name = b.name
       ) AS x
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT a.id, a.name
          FROM test
          JOIN (
                 SELECT MAX(number2) AS m,
                        name
                   FROM test
                  GROUP BY name
               ) AS b ON a.name = b.name
       ) AS y ON x.id = y.id   /* id matching */
```